# Incorrect Paths for an Imported Flex Project

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm trying to import someone else's Flex project folder into Flash Builder 4.5, and I'm having some problems with the paths. When I load everything up, I'm getting errors that say that the "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant" for all the .as files living in **src**. It looks like based on the path settings, it cannot find those files.

So I went to the **Package > Properties** and tried to add the src folder to the Source Path list, but no luck there either.

One curious thing is that when I look at the error at the bottom, I see **Path** is set to **/ProjectName/src/**. Is that an absolute path? Certainly it wouldn't find them if it were.

Can anyone shed some light on getting my Flex project to find my **src** folder?

Thanks,

Whit

Comment: Sounds like you might have some problems with the Flex library imports themselves due to importing the project files... you probably want to give this a shot, just create a new Flex project (make sure it compiles hello world label in there) then copy and paste the source over from the project you attempted to import.  Alternatively in the properties on the existing project check out the flex library path and remove and re-add the SDK.

Comment: Did you check Project > Properties > **Flash Build Path** to make sure "Main Source Folder" is set to "src"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/ProjectName/foo/bar in Flash Builder would be resolved to the project's foo/bar directory, therefore it is not an absolute path.

The project you experience may also have to do with the libraries (SWCs) referenced by your project are not properly referenced.  You may go to `Project -> Properties -> Flex Build Path -> Library path (tab)` and add reference to libraries similar to the fashion you add the Source Path.

Additionally, when source path is correctly added, you would also notice a "virtual folder" appearing in the referencing project, which allows you to directly load and edit the source code of the referenced project.